How can I use nginx reverse proxy in three docker containers?
I hope you are doing well.
My site consists of three parts.

I developed the front-end part with Angular
the back-end section with Nest JS
the database is MongoDB.

My goal is to have each of these sections run in a separate Docker container.
Suppose the names of the containers are as follows.

angularContainer
nestContainer
databaseContainer

The connection between the nestContainer and databaseContainer is established with the network. And to prevent ephemeral, volume has been used in the databaseContainer.
My questions and challenges:

I want to use nginx. Should I install nginx in each of angularContainer and nestContainer? Or just install an nginx on the host?
What is the best practice for running Angular inside the container? I want to use the dist folder.
What is the best practice for running nestjs inside the container? I want to use the dist folder.
I want to use Reverse Proxy for containers. so that the angularContainer is called with the mysite.com and the nestContainer is called with the api.mysite.com. How can I achieve this?

If you show some simple examples to guide me. I will be very grateful.

Please ask only one question at a time.  I have a sample setup in "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend that might help.  For CORS purposes and to simplify the front-end deployment, you might find it easier to use a single DNS name (ideally not built into the application at all) and use only HTTP path-based routing.
